# when I make custom exception class, How can I invokes the base constructor with the provided argument?

Tags: c#, exception

I want to throw exceptions by using the exception fields.
Should I put in the exception constructor method?
I keep trying to use them but I can't make it.
what should I do?

'''

```
class AccountException : Exception
{
    public string ACCOUNT_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
    public string CREDIT_LIMIT_HAS_BEEN_EXCEEDED;
    public string NAME_NOT_ASSOCIATED_WITH_ACCOUNT;
    public string NO_OVERDRAFT;
    public string PASSWORD_INCORRECT;
    public string USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
    public string USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN;

    public AccountException() : base()
    {
    }
    public AccountException(string type) : base()
    {   
      // what should I do
    }
}

    public void Login(string password)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(password.GetHashCode()) == this.password)
            {
                IsAuthenticated = true;
            }
            else if (Convert.ToString(password.GetHashCode()) != this.password)
            {
                throw new AccountException("PASSWORD_INCORRECT");
            }
        }
        catch(AccountException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
       
    }
```

'''

Comment: Do you want to obtain an exception with the message "PASSWORD_INCORRECT " when your program throws your `AccountException("PASSWORD_INCORRECT")`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want

Comment: ok, so you can try the solution below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain an exception class that return your message (e.g. "PASSWORD_INCORRECT") you can call the base constructor with the message parameter like this:

```cs
public AccountException(string message) : base(message)
{
}
```

NOTE: if I can give you a suggestion don't use a lot of string attributes like:

```cs
public string ACCOUNT_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
public string CREDIT_LIMIT_HAS_BEEN_EXCEEDED;
public string NAME_NOT_ASSOCIATED_WITH_ACCOUNT;
public string NO_OVERDRAFT;
public string PASSWORD_INCORRECT;
public string USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
public string USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN;
```

Instead, create an enum with all available string like:

```cs
class AccountException: Exception
{

    public AccountException() : base()
    {
    }
    public AccountException(AccountExceptionMessages message) : base(message.ToString())
    {
    }
}

public void Login(string password)
{
    try
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(password.GetHashCode()) == this.password)
        {
            IsAuthenticated = true;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToString(password.GetHashCode()) != this.password)
        {
            throw new AccountException(AccountExceptionMessages.PASSWORD_INCORRECT);
        }
    }
    catch(AccountException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
   
}

public enum AccountExceptionMessages
{
  
    ACCOUNT_DOES_NOT_EXIST = 0,
    CREDIT_LIMIT_HAS_BEEN_EXCEEDED = 1,
    NAME_NOT_ASSOCIATED_WITH_ACCOUNT = 2,
    NO_OVERDRAFT = 3,
    PASSWORD_INCORRECT = 4,
    USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST = 5,
    USER_NOT_LOGGED_IN = 6,
}
```